# Upgraded bootstrap 3 to 4f, now nav menu doesn't show

Tags: c#, css, razor

No changes to the code, shown below.
Upgraded bootstrap from 3.2 to 4.3.1.
Now, the menu
 - shows as a line on the left
 - hamburger menu doesn't show regardless of window size
 - expands and collapses similar to the hamburger menu

I've updated the navbar-inverse to  navbar-dark, but can't find any other changes to make.

Collapsed
[image: Like this - collapsed]
Expanded
[image]

Before  upgrading, correct
[image]

```
@using Portal.Helpers;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Center For People In Need @ViewBag.Title</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="@Url.Action(" Index", "Home" )"><img src="/Content/Logo.png" alt="l" class="logo" /></a>
            @*<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="/Content/Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" /></a>*@
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @{var UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();}
                @if (UserRoles.Contains("ClientUser") || UserRoles.Contains("ClientAdmin")) {
                    <li class="@Html.SelectedClass(TempData["activemenu"], "Clients")">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Clients", "Index", "Clients")
                    </li>
                }
...
```

Comment: there are major changes in v4, you should review v4 documentation. the list item class should be `nav-item` and the link `nav-link`.   `<ul class="nav"><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li></ul>`

Comment: @iSR5 You are not kidding. That is a huge set of changes. Were those deprecated before they were dropped? I've moved back to 3 and everything is working fine. We'll move to 4 intentionally and when it is needed. Thanks.

Comment: some features were replaced others are just extended and added more options. check this out : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many changes in Bootstrap v.4, It's better to read its documentation in order to fix problems:
[Bootstrap Navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) and [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) can help you.